Where can I find the "Add Items" command in Acumatica 2024 R1?
In version 2022 R2 the source code has the following for a button on the grid section of the Sales Orders screen, with the command "AddInvBySite".
 <CustomItems>
     <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Add Items" Key="cmdASI">
         <AutoCallBack Command="AddInvBySite" Target="ds">
             <Behavior CommitChanges="True" PostData="Page" />
         </AutoCallBack>
     </px:PXToolBarButton>

And here's the source code, easily findable:
    public PXAction<SOOrder> addInvBySite;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Items", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable AddInvBySite(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (sitestatus.AskExt((PXGraph g, string viewName) => sitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear()) == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            return AddInvSelBySite(adapter);
        }
        sitestatusfilter.Cache.Clear();
        sitestatus.Cache.Clear();
        return adapter.Get();
    }

I'm upgrading to 2024 R1, and I see the same button ("Add Items") - with a different command, "ShowItems".  The problem is, I can't find this action / command anywhere in the source code / BLC for that page...
<CustomItems>
    <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Add Items" Key="cmdASI">
        <AutoCallBack Command="ShowItems" Target="ds">
        <Behavior CommitChanges="True" PostData="Page" />
        </AutoCallBack>
    </px:PXToolBarButton>

Any idea where I can find that  'ShowItems' command?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Unless you write your code with a graphics editor, you do not need to post it as an image. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post much more easily than you can capture an image.

How do you propose I highlight a section of interest of that code the way I did?  It's the most expeditious way of displaying my issue.

Samvel (below, who answered my question) obviously understood completely what I was looking for.

It doesn't matter that someone was able to understand you. It matters that the guidelines here say not to use images unless absolutely necessary, for the many reasons that are in the post I linked. Please follow those guidelines in the future. To indicate problem areas of the code, you can add comments around the area you want to highlight.

Those guidelines make no sense.  If you could explain to me why images, when used properly and judiciously, are not supported - I'll understand.  Otherwise I won't.

The article I linked explains it very well. It lists quite a few reasons why they should be avoided. Did you read it? And whether you understand or agree is irrelevant - they're the guidelines here, and they're not optional. If you don't want to follow them, you shouldn't be posting here.

That method is part of the PX.Objects.Extensions.AddItemLookup.AddItemLookupBaseExt<TGraph, TDocument, TItemInfo, TItemFilter> abstract graph extension.
It is implemented by PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.SOOrderEntryExt.SOOrderSiteStatusLookupExt for SOOrderEntry.
